# How to print a PostScript file in Evince using a brochure layout?

Tags: printing, evince

I have an PostScript output from a man page produced by `man -t ssh > man_ssh.ps`. It opens for viewing in Evince Document Viewer. I want to print it on a printer that supports double-sided printing. So, I'd like to print it in 'brochure' mode - that is, when four pages of a document are printed on two sides single sheet, so when the sheets are folded in half all at once, the numeration of the pages of a document is like in a booklet. How can I print the document this way in Evince?

UPD: There is one more question, how to make `man -t` output comply to booklet page layout - that is, wider inner margins, making pages 'left' and 'right'?

Comment: +1. that's the only reason I sometimes have to resort to acroread

Comment: The only way I've found so far is to use `psbook` from `psutils` package. It will rearrange the pages in the input document, so they're in the booklet order in the output. However, it won't honor the page number caption position (they will appear on the same position, "left" or "right", not on "outer" or "inner"), since the input is already formatted by `man`.

Comment: @type: Perhaps not, see my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like currently there's no way to print pages in brochure (booklet) mode neither in Evince nor in Xpdf. There is a semi-solution to use `psbook` utility from the `pstools` package that will rearrange and output the pages in the postscript file so they go as in booklet mode. Please note the `-s` option of the `psbook` which controls the number of original pages that would go into one booklet. This is useful when you want to print large amount of pages that is not going to be folded all at once, but folded into several sub-booklets. For example, 120-page document would go into 30-sheet brochure by default, which is hard to fold. Using the `psbook -s 24` will make 120/24=5 brochures 6 sheets each, which are easy to fold and then to combine together.

Also note that `man -t` output is not well prepared for booklet printing - it has page numbers on "right" side, not on the "outer" side, and "left" and "right" page margins are the same instead of "inner" margin being larger than "outer", and pages are not classified as "left" and "right". Discussion on how to tweak the `man -t` output goes [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16265/).

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to configure CUPS so that it calls `pdfbook` for me. The process boils down to the following:

1. In your CUPS server (e.g., `http://localhost:631`), create a copy of the configuration for the printer you want to enable brochure printing for. Let's call the new printer "Print-booklet".
2. Edit `/etc/cups/ppd/Print-booklet.ppd` as root. Add the following line, e.g., before the `*cupsFilter` entry: `*cupsPreFilter: "application/pdf 0 booklettopdf"`.
3. (This step is a bit messy, perhaps it can be done in a cleaner way.) In 
   `/usr/lib/cups/filter`, create the script `booklettopdf` (as root):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   for e in "$@"; do echo DEBUG: $0: $e 1>&2; done
   TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
   echo DEBUG: $0: $TMPFILE 1>&2
   if [ "$6" = "" ]; then
       cat
   else
       cat "$6"
   fi | pdfbook --scale 0.97 --outfile $TMPFILE && cat $TMPFILE && rm $TMPFILE
   ```
4. Make the script executable: `chmod +x booklettopdf`.
5. Print a test page.

Now, whenever you want to print in booklet format, choose the new printer "Print-booklet".

The `cupsPreFilter` is a [CUPS PPD extension](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/spec-ppd.html), and it seems that the `application/pdf` format will always appear in the filter chain (Ubuntu 12.10, perhaps earlier?).

I'd vote for integrating this functionality into CUPS.

Comment: In your script, if you use `/bin/bash`, everything after the first line can be replaced with this: `cat "${6:-/dev/stdin}" | pdfbook --scale 0.97 --outfile /dev/stdout` . Then you don't need any temporary file.

Comment: @StefanSeidel: For some reason I had trouble using `pdfbook` to print to `stdout` in the context of a filter. Don't remember the details, though. Does your code work for you? -- Note that printing a test page is different from printing from, say, `evince`.